# SharePoint newly created Group's description is not fetched using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, groups

I use below code to get the SharePoint Site group's data. Description of the default groups like owners, visitors were fetched correctly but the same code returns null for newly created group's description and these newly created groups have description mentioned in SharePoint Site.

```
            using (ctx)
            {
                var groups = ctx.LoadQuery(ctx.Web.SiteGroups);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (var temp in groups)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(temp.Title + "->" + temp.Description);
                }
            }
```